# How do I manage / delete my Azure logic app connections

Tags: azure-logic-apps

We are building a logic app in Azure.

It consists of an Office 365 new mail item and a service bus queue item.

What we cant work out is how to manage / delete the connections:

[image]

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Reference MSDN blog**

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/logicapps/2016/04/13/browsing-api-connections-in-the-azure-portal/

**Using Powershell to manage connections**
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/logicapps/2016/03/18/using-powershell-to-manage-api-connections/

There is a first class UI support also available now in Azure Portal

[image]

 **Update:** connections are now supported in the resource explorer

[image]

 Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few options available:-

1. Search for API connections -> Click on the connection you want to delete.
2. Go to your resource group -> Overview -> List of items available in resources will be shown -> Click on the item(type - API Connection). -> Delete.

Answer (score 2):

For sake of completeness, you can access the API connections associated to your Logic App from the options menu:

[image: API Connections]