# Delete existing connections in an Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

How do I delete any of the existing connections for a connector in my logic app?

[image: Azure]

I have tried lots of stuff but can't seem too find the answer.

Comment: This is almost a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37605480/how-do-i-manage-delete-my-azure-logic-app-connections but the other question and answer is out of date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every connection that you create creates an api connection entity in your resource group. For example, I have two connections for O365 outlook as shown below
[image: Connection Names]

[image: Respective connections that are created]

You simply delete the api connection and it deletes the entry from the logic app.
Refer screen shot after I delete office365 connection

[image]